# Solving Diophantine equations

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

Given a complex number $z$ and a positive integer $n$, I would like to be able to find integer solutions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to the Diophantine equation
$$0 < a^2\vert z \vert^2 + \beta\textrm{ Re}(z) + \gamma^2 \leq n.$$
As an example, I tried

```
z := 2 + 3*i
Solve[0 < a^2*Norm[z^2] + b*Re[z] + c^2 <= 100,{a,b,c},Integers]
```

But when I hit return+shift I got "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve". Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and offer a method which will work? Thanks.

Comment: You have a couple of errors there. For one thing, Mma uses I not i.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want:

```
z = 2 + 3*I;
rul = FindInstance[0 < a^2*Norm[z^2] + b*Re[z] + c^2 <= 100, {a, b, c}, Integers, 5]
```

Change the 5 for more or less.

Check the answers:

```
0 < a^2*Norm[z^2] + b*Re[z] + c^2 <= 100 /. rul
```

To store the answers:

```
a^2*Norm[z^2] + b*Re[z] + c^2 /. rul
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to take the solutions $(a,b,c)$ and plug them back into the equation to obtain and store the values of $a^2\vert z \vert^2 + b\textrm{ b}(z) + c^2 $ at those points?

Comment: I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to directly list out the finitely many real numbers $x \in (0,n]$ such that
$$x = a^2\vert z \vert^2 + b\textrm{Re}(z) + c^2$$
for some integers $a,b,c$? It appears that there are infinitely many solutions to the Diophantine equation I posted, but only finitely many such $x$.

Comment: The x you have there is what is inside of FindInstance. If there are a finite number of real x (which I doubt) then it is a large number.

Comment: There must be a finite number because the set of such points $x$ is a lattice in a bounded region.

Comment: I stopped at 5000, that ain't infinite but I got the feeling there were a lot more. Just try FindInstance[0 < a^2*Norm[z^2] + b*Re[z] + c^2 <= 1, {a, b, c}, Reals, 5000]

Comment: Yes, there are infinitely many solutions to he inequality. I'm saying there are only finitely many numbers of the form $$a^2\vert z \vert^2 + b\textrm{Re}(z) + c^2$$ that are between $0$ and $n$

Comment: The way you described x and the inequality are the same thing.

Comment: Right, I'm just asking how to find all of the finitely many $x$ between $0$ and $n$. Finding solutions $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ to the inequality and plugging them back in seems a bit problematic since there are infinitely many solutions $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ to the inequality.

Comment: If you run the last line of my post which is finding the x you are looking for you should see that they are all >0 and <=n.